# Add new column on csv file in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

import pandas as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

```
dframe_final.to_csv('C:/Program Files/source/csv_data/2015/Merged files/jjj_all_merged.csv')
```

I have this part of my code and I need to add a new column at the end of this csv file and name it "New_name".
And populate it based on different criteria:

For example, if cell1 is "a" and cell2 is "b" and cell3 is "1" and cell4 is "2 or 5" then enter "OK" 
If not, enter "NOT OK" or leave empty.

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4    "New_name"
a              b           1           2            "OK"
a              b           1           5            "OK"
c              d           e           f          "NOT OK"
```

PLEASE HELP!!! :)

Comment: Read this 10 min introduction to pandas. It'll give you all the basic functions of pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: #Code below creates a new column in the aaa_all_merge file and add entries based on multiple  criterias
csv_input = np.read_csv('G:Flic_all_merged.csv')
mask = (dframe_final['aaa'] == '159') & (dframe_final['bbb'].isin(['A','B','C']))
dframe_final['Final'] == np.where(mask,'OK',' not OK')

This part doesn't work. I dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
mask = (df['Column 1'] == 'a') & (df['Column 2'] == 'b') & (df['Column 3'] == '1') & (df['Column 4'].isin(['2','5']))
df['new_value'] = np.where(mask,'OK','NOT OK')
```

Output:

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 "New_name" new_value
0        a        b        1        2       "OK"        OK
1        a        b        1        5       "OK"        OK
2        c        d        e        f   "NOT OK"    NOT OK
```

Comment: @extrero01 if this solution helped yo would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) it.

Comment: I am having an error code on the last line.
dframe_final["final'] = np.where(mask , 'ok' ,'not ok')

Comment: @extrero01  what is the error code you are getting?

Comment: G:\J\Python 2017>python_final.py
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (2,17,18,22,23,24,25) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2522, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Final_reserves'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\J\Python 2017\python_final.py", line 98, in <module>
    dframe_final['Final_reserves'] == np.where(mask,'OK','NOT OK')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

Comment: File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3838, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

Comment: File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2524, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Final_reserves'

Comment: Check your column names in the mask statement.  I suspect you might have an errant column name.  Or maybe a extra space or something.

Comment: I created a test file with this code.  

import pandas as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
dframe_final = np.read_csv('G:/J/Python 2017/F_all_merged1.csv',dtype='str',
   usecols=['Block','Policy number','base','Plan code','Insurance type','Status','State','Issue age','Duration','Attained age','Sex','Issue year','Expiration year','Face Amount','cash value','PEV reserves','Face Amount','Final_reserves'],
   low_memory=False)
mask = (dframe_final['Block'] == '159') & (dframe_final['Insurance type'].isin(['T','U','L']))
dframe_final['Final_reserves'] = np.where(mask,'OK','NOT OK')

Comment: Now i get this error code

G:\J\Python 2017>test_python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\J\Python 2017\test_python.py", line 101, in <module>
    dframe_final['Final_reserves'] = np.where(mask,'OK','NOT OK')
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'where'

Comment: Your naming convention is not standard.  Normally you would `import pandas as pd` and `import numpy as np`.. And, that is your problem.  You aliased np to pandas which is not correct.  Therefore, np.where, pandas.where and not numpy.where.

Comment: Oh I see...so just adding import numpy as np after the pandas statement will fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
with open('csv_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                fwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='/', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                fwriter.writerow(List_to_add)
```

`a` in options means 'append'. Then I imported the csv file as 'pd.DataFrame'.

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')
```

I do not know if this is the best way.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
```

You will need above two things.